# Validar si el usuario es mayor de edad

Tags: javascript, java, validación, aplicación-web

Tengo un incoveniente estoy haciendo una app web y me piden que si el usuario es mayor de 18 años pueda registrarse y si no salga algun mensaje. La verdad de javascript se muy poco. Si me pudieran ayudar lo agradeceria mucho, dejo el codigo del formulario y el js de como lo estoy validando gracias:

FORM:

```
<h:form id="formularioRegistro" class="form-horizontal">
    <legend>Registro de usuarios</legend>

    <!-- nombre-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nombre" >Nombres:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="30" class="form-control input-md"   tabindex="1" ></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Apellido-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="apellido">Apellidos:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="apellido" name="apellido" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="2"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Documento-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="documento">N° Documento:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="documento" name="documento" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="3"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Email-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="correo">Email:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="correo"  name="correo" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="abcde@hotmail.com"  tabindex="4"   ></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contraseña-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="contrasena"  name="contrasena" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********"  tabindex="5" ></input> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Confirmar contraseña-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="repetirContraseña">Confirmar contraseña:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="repetirContraseña" name="repetirContraseña" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********"  tabindex="6"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Direccion-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="direccion">Dirección:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="50" tabindex="7"></input>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Telefono-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tel">Teléfono:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="tel" name="tel" type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="8"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Ciudad -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="form-control"  tabindex="10" >
                <option selected="true" disabled="true">Seleccione Ciudad...</option>
                <c:forEach var="objCiudad" items="#{controladorCiudad.listarCiudades()}">
                    <option value="#{objCiudad.idCiudad}">#{objCiudad.nombreCiudad}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fecha -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fechaN">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="fechaN" name="fechaN" type="date" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="11"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="genero">Genero:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="genero" name="genero" class="form-control"  tabindex="10" >
                <option selected="true" disabled="true">Seleccione Genero...</option>
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label class="col-md-5 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="confirmar" name="confirmar" ></input>Acepto términos y condiciones</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="condicion" class="col-md-12">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <u>Para registarse en Effective Orderrs debe diligenciar todos los campos</u>
    </div> 

    <!-- Boton -->
    <div id="boton">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Boton"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h:commandButton id="Boton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrarme" action="#{controladorUsuario.registrarUsuario()}" tabindex="12"></h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

**VALIDACION FORMULARIO**

```
$().ready(function () {

    $('#formularioRegistro').formValidation({// Validación datos capa cliente. TENER PRESENTE EL ID DEL FORM
        err: {container: 'tooltip'}, //muestra en tooltips
        icon: {valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', invalid: 'fa fa-thumbs-down', validating: 'fa fa-refresh'}, //iconos
        //locale: 'es_ES', //idioma - debe enlazar el archivo "es_ES.js"
        fields: {
            nombre: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un nombre válido '

                    },
                  regexp: {
                       regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo letras, sin números o caracteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        message: 'Minimo 3'
                    }
                }
            },
            apellido: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un apellido válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo letras, sin números o caracteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        message: 'Minimo 3'
                    }
                }
            },
            documento: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un documento válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo números'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 caracteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            correo: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un correo válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carecteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 caracteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            contrasena: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese una contraseña válida'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carecteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 caracteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            repetirContraseña: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese una contraseña válida'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carecteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 caracteres'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'contraseña',
                        message: 'Las contraseñas no coinciden'
                    }
                }
            },
            direccion: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese una dirección válida'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan caracteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        message: 'Minimo 10 caracteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            tel: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un telefono válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9-]+$/,
                        message: 'Sólo numeros'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 7,
                        message: 'Minimo 7 caracteres'
                    }
                }

            },
            ciudad: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe elegir su ciudad',
                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the selected options
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('ciudad').val();
                            return (options !== null && options.length >= 1 && options.length <= 4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
               genero: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe elegir su genero',
                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the selected options
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('genero').val();
                            return (options !== null && options.length >= 1 && options.length <= 10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'confirmar[]': {
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Debe aceptar terminos y condiciones'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 1,
                        message: 'Debe aceptar terminos y condiciones'
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Para empezar te falta el campo edad: es mucho más fácil que el usuario escriba su edad en el formulario, a calcularlo en base a su documento de identidad.

Comment: @SalahAdDin tiene la fecha de nacimiento, con eso podrias conocer la edad

Comment: Que plugin de jquery estas utilizando para las validaciones ? sera quizas http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: Hola Lina. Veo que utilizas JSF para tu `<h:form>` pero no para los componentes internos como `<input>` en lugar de `<h:inputText>`. ¿Cuál es la causa de esto? ¿Quizás por aplicar las validaciones de jquery cambiaste los componentes?

Comment: Si exactemente, para poder validar en formValidation necesito los name y en el h:inputText este atributo no lo tiene!

Comment: En JSF el nombre de un componente se basa en el id del componente. Si declaras `<h:form id="formulario"> <h:inputText id="nombre" /> </h:form>` verás un HTML generado similar a `<form id="formulario"> <input type="text" id="formulario:nombre" name="formulario:nombre" /> </form>`. Allí puedes ubicar el nombre de tu componente HTML y utilizarlo en tu validación jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso deberias escribir un nuevo validador

[Writing new validator](http://formvalidation.io/developing/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    FormValidation.Validator.mayorEdad = {
        validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
            var value = $field.val();
            
           
            var fechanacimiento = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY");
          
            if(!fechanacimiento.isValid())
                return false;
          
            var years = moment().diff(fechanacimiento, 'years');
          
            return years > 18;
               
        }
    };

    $('#formularioRegistro').formValidation({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            fechaN: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'La fecha de nacimiento es requerida'
                    },
                    mayorEdad: {
                        message: 'No es mayor de edad'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/framework/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>


<form id="formularioRegistro" class="form-horizontal">
    <legend>Registro de usuarios</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fechaN">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="fechaN" name="fechaN" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="11"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div id="boton">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Boton"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="Boton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrarme" action="#{controladorUsuario.registrarUsuario()}" tabindex="12"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Con la ayuda de moment.js puedes calcular el cumpleaños para ver si es mayor a 18 y hacer que la validacion custom pase correctamente.

Comment: Escrito por @Lina: "Hola,Leandro me sirve mucho tu código, pero al probarlo solo me acepta como valido antes de esta fecha 30/03/1997 por ejemplo yo nací el 27/01/1998 es decir que ya tengo 18 años y me aparece como no valido, que aun soy menor de edad. Que cambios le hago a tu código para que haga esto? Muchas gracias por ayudarme!"

Comment: El problema seguramente se presente cuando moment parsea la fecha, no se que browser usas, si es IE podrias poner un breakpoint en el codigo y evaluar si pasa por el isValid() o si usas Chrome usar la developer tools ,a la cual accedes con F12, y poder poner un breakpoint alli para evaluar que valor esta tomando.

Comment: @Leandro Tuttini: Creo que realmente el ajuste que le hace falta a tu función es cambiar `return years > 18` por `return years >= 18`. Un saludo! :)